# Process not ending in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a script to read a file that can be 10s of gigs big and i want to use multiprocessing to process it.

This is a compression algorithm where i want the user to define a buffer, then 3 processes will start, one to read the buffer amount of lines from the file, pass the lines to the processing process, then pass the processed lines to a process that writes the lines to a new file. I want all this to happen simultaneously, and for each process to wait for the next bundle of lines.

I already have the script, but when i run it, it doesn't end. I think something is wrong with the processes. I think it has to do with the islice in my read function, but i don't know how to write it better.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
from itertools import islice

def read(from_filename, buffer, process_queue):
  file = open(from_filename, 'r')
  slice = islice(file, buffer)
  while slice:
    to_process = []
    for line in slice:
      to_process.append(line)
    process_queue.put(to_process)
  process_queue.put('kill')

def write(to_filename, write_queue):
  to_file = open(to_filename, 'a+')
  while 1:
    to_write = write_queue.get()
    if to_write == 'kill':
      break
    to_file.write(to_write + '\n')

def compress(process_queue, write_queue):
  while 1:
    to_process = process_queue.get()
    if to_process == 'kill':
      write_queue.put('kill')
      break
    # process, put output in to_write
    write_queue.put(to_write)

def decompress(process_queue, write_queue):
  while 1:
    to_process = process_queue.get()
    if to_process == 'kill':
      write_queue.put('kill')
      break
    # process, put output in to_write
    write_queue.put(to_write)

def main():
  option = raw_input("C for Compress OR D for Decompress: ")
  from_file = raw_input("Enter input filename: ")
  buf = int(raw_input("Enter line buffer: "))
  to_file = raw_input("Enter output filename: ")
  start = time.time()
  write_queue = mp.Queue()
  process_queue = mp.Queue()
  reader = mp.Process(target=read, args=(from_file, buf, process_queue))
  writer = mp.Process(target=write, args=(to_file, write_queue))
  if option == 'c' or option == 'C':
    processor = mp.Process(target=compress, args=(process_queue, write_queue))
  elif option == 'd' or option == 'D':
    processor = mp.Process(target=decompress, args=(process_queue, write_queue))
  else:
    print "Invalid Options..."
  writer.start()
  processor.start()
  reader.start()
  reader.join()
  processor.join()
  writer.join()
  end = time.time()
  elapsed = (end - start)
  print "\n\nTotal Time Elapsed: " + str(elapsed) + " secs"

if __name__=='__main__':
  main()
```

This is my first attempt at multiprocessing.
When i run it, it doesn't end. I think a process is stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code is wrong:

```
def read(from_filename, buffer, process_queue):
  file = open(from_filename, 'r')
  slice = islice(file, buffer)
  while slice:
    to_process = []
    for line in slice:
      to_process.append(line)
    process_queue.put(to_process)
  process_queue.put('kill')
```

Since `slice` is a `islice` object the condition `while slice` will always be true, hence it's like having a `while True` there. You should re-create the slice object every time.

```
def read(from_filename, buffer, process_queue):
  file = open(from_filename, 'r')

  while True:
    slice = islice(file, buffer)
    to_process = []
    for line in slice:
      to_process.append(line)
    process_queue.put(to_process)
    if not to_process:
        # input ended
        break
  process_queue.put('kill')
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
def read_chunk(file, buffer):
    return [file.readline() for _ in xrange(buffer)]
    # or, "more" equivalent to using islice
    #return [line for i,line in itertools.izip(xrange(buffer), file)]

def read(from_filename, buffer, process_queue):
  file = open(from_filename, 'r')

  for to_process in iter(lambda: read_chunk(file, buffer), []):
    process_queue.put(to_process)
  process_queue.put('kill')
```

Note that it doesn't make sense to use `itertools.islice` if you have to build a list anyway.